# $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2 + e^2=f^2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I don't mean to ask for the solution but there is a challenging word problem that I have no idea how to start and would appreciate some help thanks.

What is the smallest value of $f$ that satisfies $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2 + e^2=f^2$?

Comment: What are the restrictions on $a,b,c,d,e,f$? Positive integers?

Comment: By the way, as stated, it's not really a "word problem".

Comment: This seems to stretch the meaning of  "word problem".

Comment: (13 seconds...)

Comment: I anticipated your comment!

Answer (score 1):

Hint (assuming $a,b,c,d,e,f$ must be positive integers): Can you get $f=1$? $2$? $3$? $4$?

Answer (score 1):

If $0$ is allowed, the answer is $0$.  If all the variables have to be positive integers the left side is at least $5$ and $9$ doesn't work.  If you can do $16$ you are done.

Answer (score 0):

the smallest square that is the sum of five **distinct** positive squares is
$$ 10^2 =  7^2 + 5^2 + 4^2 + 3^2 + 1^2  $$

The only square that is the sum of more than one **consecutive**  positive squares, beginning with $1,$ is
$$ 70^2 = 1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 + 4^2 + \cdots + 24^2 \; .  $$
This leads to one construction of the Leech Lattice. See page 130 in the second edition of *Lattices and Codes* by Wolfgang Ebeling. The raw fact is proved in Mordell's book, *Diophantine Equations*.

Comment: what if the numbers do not to be distinct, only positive?

Comment: @unknown look at the other answers